# Why does resource prefetching not work in IE11?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, prefetch

Have a look at this slideshow:

http://www.jungledragon.com/all/slideshow/promoted

It loads one big image, and in the bottom there are 9 thumbnail images, which you can see when you toggle the thumbs icon button.

As a test in speeding up this slideshow, I'm including link prefetch statements for the large version of each thumb:

```
    <link rel="prefetch" [large image url 1 here]" />
    <link rel="prefetch" [large image url 2 here]" />
    <link rel="prefetch" [large image url 3 here]" />
    <link rel="prefetch" [large image url 4 here]" />
    <link rel="prefetch" [large image url 5 here]" />
    <link rel="prefetch" [large image url 6 here]" />
    <link rel="prefetch" [large image url 7 here]" />
    <link rel="prefetch" [large image url 8 here]" />
    <link rel="prefetch" [large image url 9 here]" />
```

You'll find  the above in the source of the page. The idea is that all large versions of the current batch (9 images) are preloaded so that when users navigate the slideshow, the large images often appear instantly.

Having implemented this, I've been testing the effects. The test instruction is simple:

- Visit the slide show link
- Wait for a few seconds (to allow the preloading)
- Move to the next image a few times. If this works nearly instantly, prefetching was succesful. If an image load takes 2-3 seconds, it means it failed.

Alternatively, you can also open your browser's inspector window, network tab, and see both the preloading the the retrieval from cache. Note that if you do this test multiple times, you need to clear the cache each time.

**Chrome results**

The results in Chrome are spectacular. The prefetch hints are picked up aggressively. It's as good as it gets.

**Firefox results**

Firefox prefetches less aggressively and more slowly. Still, at least it does prefetch, and it works.

**IE11 results**

IE11 claims to support resource prefetching but it has zero effect. In Windows 8.1/IE11, none of the images are loaded instantly, it seems to prefecth nothing, also not by waiting a long time before navigating the slideshow. In IE's dev tools, I can confirm that the network tab shows no prefetch activity.

I learned later on that prefetching does not work with the dev tools open, but even when closed there is no prefetching going on, I can see that from the response times.

Any idea on why this works for Chrome and Firefox, yet not for IE11? It should be well supported but I cannot get it to work. This is a cross-domain fetch, both HTTP, not HTTPs, yet cross-domain prefetching should work according to the spec.

Comment: You can use the excellent Fiddler tool by Telerik to see the images being downloaded without needing to use the "Network" tab in your dev tools. http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Comment: Looking at MSDN - "IE11 supports up to ten (10) prefetch requests. Additional requests are ignored." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ie/dn265039(v=vs.85).aspx - are any requests (stylesheets, scripts etc.) being made before the images?

Comment: @pwdst Yes, but not prefetch requests.

Comment: @pwdst Regarding Fiddler, thanks but even without it is clear that IE11 is prefetching nothing in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked at the link you have provided and I believe the issue is the unusual and (probably) invalid placement of the link elements.

Microsoft state-

> > The link element can be used only within the head tag.

Within their [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ie/ms535848(v=vs.85).aspx).

[Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link) state-

> > Permitted parent elements Any element that accept metadata elements

This tallies with the [official specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-link-element) which further defines Metadata content-

> > Metadata content is content that sets up the presentation or behavior of the rest of the content, or that sets up the relationship of the document with other documents, or that conveys other "out of band" information.
> >
> > base link meta noscript script style template title

The page head is able to contain metadata content whereas the body is only able to accept sectioning and flow content.

Comment: Thank you, just implemented and tested this, and indeed this way it does work!

Comment: Something like this should always be in the HEAD element. dns-prefetch is another example. You want these background tasks running as early as possible. You also need to consider, are these requests blocking other requests on that domain? remember a browser will open (typically) 6 connections at once to the same domain. I don't know if the prefetch counts towards that # or not.

Comment: @ChrisLove Prefetch and pre-render utilise browser **idle** time to download resources that it is "highly likely" the user will require in the near future - particularly the next request. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Link_prefetching_FAQ. In the case of dns-prefetch, MDN describe this as being "in parallel" with content download - but will be to the DNS server of the user, and not the web server. The amount of traffic for a DNS lookup is actually extremely small, the advantage of the pre-fetch is mitigating the relatively high latency for the lookup.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add that i just found out that `prerender` will not work if running your site through visual studio (using any other port than 443 or 80) with IE11/Edge. Chrome was working fine and i was trying to determine why ie/edge wasn't working. The only thing i could think of is the port. So i published to our web server and ie/edge started working. I would assume the same thing would hold true for `prefetch` but i haven't tried it.